# zoom in and zoom out images for training dataset augmentation

Tags: python, data-augmentation

I want to train a deep learning model with some image data. Since my dataset is small, I want to perform a zoom-in and zoom-out augmentation to get a 3 times larger dataset. I have done the zoom-in operation as follows:

```
            img = cv2.imread(path),0)
            new_width = int(img.shape[1] * 1.2)  # Zoom in by 20%
            new_height = int(img.shape[0] * 1.2)  # Zoom in by 20%
            zoomed_frame = cv2.resize(img, (new_width, new_height)) #resize to smaller dimensions
            roi_x = (new_width - img.shape[1]) // 2
            roi_y = (new_height - img.shape[0]) // 2
            roi_frame = zoomed_frame[roi_y:roi_y+img.shape[0], roi_x:roi_x+img.shape[1]]
            img = cv2.resize(roi_frame, (64, 64), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

here I first resize the image to 20% larger, then I crop the image of the size of original image from the center. At the end, since I have to prepare my dataset for model training, all input images must be of same size, so I resize at the end into 66*64 size.
Although I am not doubtful about the zoom-in procedure (still I request some expert to verify it),
I do not understand how to perform a zoom-out.

Suppose I simply resize my image to a 20% smaller size, I again need to resize it to 64*64 ultimately. Will that first resize that I had performed as a zoom-out actually make any difference to the final image of 64*64 size, or would it be the same as if resizing the original image to 64*64 without any zoom-out (not only visibly but for model training)?

Comment: I'd start by zooming in 20% in all of the images and establish that as a baseline (if possible, ofcourse). Then you could use the original images as zoomed out. In your current approach, how are you going to fill the missing data while zooming out? Also, you will lose some detail in the image since zooming in and out requires interpolation. I don't know any approach that doesn't to interpolation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are libraries that support different data augmentation tasks. It will be better to use those libraries instead of implementing them from scratch. Some examples of available libraries are [Albumentations](https://github.com/albumentations-team/albumentations) , [ImgAug](https://github.com/aleju/imgaug), [Augmentor](https://github.com/mdbloice/Augmentor) etc.